# JavaEE 6 and connection between two EJB by @Remote

Tags: ejb, java-ee-6, java-ee-5, openejb, geronimo

I have two EJB
One EJB has Remote interface
Second EJB try to connect to One EJB by Remote.

Under Geronimo EE 5 works fine but Geronimo EE6 fails

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GERONIMO-6232
https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12507168/ger3test.zip

Deployment plan for second EJB has dependency to one EJB

```
<sys:dependencies>
        <sys:dependency>
            <sys:groupId>m1k0.sandbox.ger3test</sys:groupId>
            <sys:artifactId>ger3testejb1</sys:artifactId>
        </sys:dependency>
    </sys:dependencies>
```

After deploy I get error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lm1k0/sandbox/ger3test/ger3testejb1/NewSession1Remote

How to create communication between two EJB in JavaEE6?
Is it my fault? Maybe OpenEJB?

Comment: Geronimo 3.0 changed some elements in deployments plan and now we should add export-package and import-package